# How to use GitHub to manage and share an already existing VS2010 project?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I have created my own project using VS2010 before,but afterwards, I want to use GitHub to help me manage and share my project between different computers and teammates.

But to use GitHub to manage a project,I found I have to first create a new repository.Then copy my whole project to this repository.Can I directly use my previous project as the GitHub repository?Which means I don't need to create a repository on another folder.

Comment: Google is your friend? http://blog.discountasp.net/using-git-with-visual-studio-2010-an-introduction-2/

Comment: I think the problem description is pretty long and there are many details to talk about.So I think stack overflow may be a better to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but you will just have make sure you commit every time you are done working on which ever computer you are using.  A suggestion is that you make your commit comments detailed.

Comment: GitHub is new to me, so could you please tell me the detail about doing this on my win7 version GitHub?Thank you very very much!

Comment: 1) First you could install this software on each computer https://windows.github.com. 2) Try following this article http://blog.discountasp.net/using-git-with-visual-studio-2010-an-introduction-2/